# Perché si dice "dire pane al pane e vino al vino?"

Tags: phrase-origin, proverbs

Come riporta il [dizionario di modi di dire del Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/P/pane.shtml#5)

> **dire pane al pane e vino al vino**
>
> Essere molto franchi, dire le cose apertamente senza lasciare possibilità di malintesi, anche a costo di essere brutali.

Qual è l'origine di questa curiosa espressione?

Comment: Domanda correlata: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-la-frase-al-pan-pan-y-al-vino-vino.

Comment: Le risposte attribuiscono l'origine alla liturgia cristiana della comunione, ma non citano nessuna fonte.

Comment: Hmm.. vorrei vedere un argomento migliore per il collegamento con la liturgia cattolica. Pane e vino sono sì importanti simboli liturgici ma anche cibi molto comuni.

Comment: Completamente d'accordo.
Infatti in un articolo di [questa rivista](http://www.archivioantropologicomediterraneo.it/riviste/estratti_12/a_cusumano.pdf) si afferma:

Comment: «Già nell’epopea di Gilgamesh, «una delle più antiche testimonianze della cultura mediterranea» (Montanari
1997: 17), il passaggio dallo stato selvaggio alla
condizione eminentemente umana di incivilimento era accompagnato dall’esortazione a mangiar pane e a bere vino, le cui offerte e libagioni
erano destinate ad alimentare il rito dei sacrifici agli dèi attestati nei diversi contesti del mondo mediterraneo. Così era per i compagni di Odisseo ma anche per gli eroi mesopotamici e per quelli egizi, per quanti traevano sostentamento da quegli essenziali beni della terra attraverso...»