# Perché diciamo "toccare ferro" mentre in altri paesi del mondo si dice "toccare legno"?

Tags: phrase-origin

In molti paesi, come scaramanzia, si dice "tocchiamo legno":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knocking_on_wood

Perché in Italia diciamo "tocchiamo ferro"?

Qual è l'origine di questa espressione?

<sup>Scusate se la domanda è un po' off-topic.</sup>

Comment: È veramente curioso. Effettivamente, in catalano diciamo "toquem fusta" e in castigliano "toquemos madera" ("fusta" e "madera" significano "legno").

Comment: Mi pareva di ricordare che fosse legato al ferro di cavallo (altro simbolo portafortuna); ho trovato qui https://www.focus.it/cultura/curiosita/perche-per-scaramanzia-si-tocca-proprio-il-ferro una spiegazione.

Comment: Equivalente di "toccare ferro" è l'espressione "toccare legno" (in inglese Knock on Wood; in francese "toucher du bois") . Il legno è ritenuto infatti un porta fortuna poiché fin dal Medioevo con questo gesto si risaliva simbolicamente alla croce lignea della crocefissione di Cristo come invocazione della protezione divina dalle sventure.  (Wikipedia)

Comment: @Gio: Quello che hai spiegato è una delle ipotesi che circolano, ma ne ho viste altre. Credo che accada lo stesso che con [questo modo di dire](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10200/). Probabilmente l'origine sia incerta.

Comment: Anche sull'origine di "toccare ferro" ci sono parecchie ipotesi in giro, alcune, secondo me, molto fantasiose. Secondo [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=0YCFE5Sfw2IC&pg=PT69&dq=%22toccare+ferro%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7jbqlzJDoAhXYWRUIHXQRCyoQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22toccare%20ferro%22&f=false) l'origine è controversa. Quindi, temo si tratterà di una domanda di risposta difficile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La frase "tocchiamo ferro" deriva da un’antica simbologia legata ai ferri di cavallo, in quanto nel medioevo si usava il ferro di cavallo per tenere lontane dalla propria casa streghe e fattucchiere.

Ancora oggi, in alcune regioni si tocca il ferro (inteso come ferro di cavallo) per avere fortuna (o per scacciare il cosiddetto "malocchio").

Mentre invece in altri paesi, come l'Inghilterra, si usa l'espressione "toccare legno" per la credenza pagana che gli spiriti vivano negli alberi.

[image: ferro di cavallo]

https://www.focus.it/cultura/curiosita/perche-per-scaramanzia-si-tocca-proprio-il-ferro
https://www.focusjunior.it/scuola/storia/perche-si-dice-toccare-ferro/
https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toccare_ferro

Comment: Come lo sai? Potresti indicare qualche fonte?

Comment: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toccare_ferro

Comment: Grazie, @Skyx! La Wikipedia, purtroppo, non è una fonte: nel migliore dei casi può dare indicazioni su quali fonti consultare (per esempio, sarebbe interessante consultare il libro di Pittano, mentre quello di Morris, che è uno studioso inglese, probabilmente parla di antropologia, non di lingua italiana). In ogni caso faresti bene a inserirla nella risposta, che così com'è sembra solo una tua opinione.

Comment: Ok, ho modificato la mia risposta con ulteriori fonti!